# Variance of Categorical Distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

I know this sounds like something I can just Google, but surprisingly, I cannot find it ANYWHERE.
All I found is a document that says: "We will skip the variance of categorical distribution here."
**Source:** https://livebook.manning.com/book/math-and-architectures-of-deep-learning/chapter-5/v-5/

I know Categorical Distribution is a generalization of the Bernoulli distribution (variance: $p(1−p)$). So what's the variance of Categorical Distribution?  $p_i(1-p_i)$?

Thank you

**Distribution Definition:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the variance of a random variable $X$ is (when it exists)
$$
\operatorname{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]
=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2
$$
Here, this is the same: if $X$ is distributed according to a categorical distribution $p$, we have
$$
\operatorname{Var}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k \left(i - \sum_{j=1}^k j p_j\right)^2 p_i = \sum_{i=1}^k i^2 p_i - \left(\sum_{i=1}^k i p_i\right)^2
$$
There is no general closed form for this.